# System menu and wifi unusable after switching from another user on Wily

Tags: wireless, 15.10, appmenu, system-tray, taskbar

I'm using the standard Unity without any custom tweaks. When I switch from another user and log in, the menu bar or panel and the Launcher appear to be frozen (but the Dash can still be controlled via keyboard) and often wifi is off until I reboot. I can use the touchpad to select things in the open windows and after some minutes, sometimes proper touchpad selection comes back on part of the system menu. But still the lack of proper wifi is a bammer.

Other users on the same laptop do not experience the problem with the menu (which I'm having ever since I tried to play a video full screen in `banshee` which got stuck to the point of not even reacting to `kill` so needed to reboot) but they do have the same wifi problem.

In case it's relevant, my kernel:

```
Linux gabor 4.2.0-21-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 2 18:42:25 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I'm on an ASUS ZENBOOK UX32V.